# Check if an object's type is from a particular namespace

Tags: c#, .net, types, namespaces

Is it possible to check if the object's type is a part of a particular namespace from C# code? If yes, how?

I need to check if `e.OriginElement as FrameworkElement` is one of the `MS.Internal` controls.

Comment: Can you not use the fully qualified type name in your cast? `e.OriginElement as MS.Internal.FrameworkElement == null`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can inspect the Type.Namespace property.

`e.OriginElement.GetType().Namespace`

Comment: Sorry, correct you were. Good thing I have commented yesterday, so my decision reason was brought up, and now everything is fair =)

Answer (score 4):

```
e.OriginElement.GetType().Namespace
```

should give you the information you need.

Comment: Since you were a minute earlier then Igby, you get the mark. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Maxim: I think you reversed your math. Look again :)